# Wrong result computing YCbCr from RGB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb

I'm working with a RGB to YCbCr converter script in MATLAB, all seems good only when calculating the Cb vector it seems that MATLAB results are not reasonable, I need to port the code to Python but I didn't understand the MATLAB result.

I've tried calculating the first elements for Y and Cr vectors manually and it seemed resonable but not the Cb vector although the equation is so simple

```
clear variables
close all
clc

fic='test.jpg';
img=imread(fic);
ti=size(img);

R=img(:,:,1);
V=img(:,:,2);
B=img(:,:,3);

Y = 0.299*R+0.587*V+0.114*B;

Cb = -0.1687*R-0.3313*V+0.5*B+128;

Cr = 0.5*R-0.4187*V-0.0813*B+128;
```

So we have `R(1,1) = 193` and `V(1,1) = 111` and `B(1,1) = 74`. When I calculate Cb manually it should give 96 (round) but `Cb(1,1)` gives 165, I don't know why ?

Comment: You are defining the zero vector to be of type uint8, haven't touched matlab in a while but can you confirm that the types can be multiplied with a float without issues? Otherwise the minus sign may also cause some issues.

Comment: I’ve removed some code that wasn’t being used, please review and make sure I didn’t break your question. You can [edit] your question at any time to change it.

Answer (score 0):

[@GlobalTraveler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900005/wrong-result-computing-ycbcr-from-rgb#comment94645766_53900005) is right. You need to convert your image to doubles first.

In MATLAB, a `double` times a `uint8` results in a `uint8`, using saturated arithmetic. So `-0.1687*R` is all zeros.

To convert the image to `double`, use  `im2double(img)`, or simply `double(img)`, depending on whether you want to keep the original range of [0,255], or convert it to [0,1] (as does `im2double`).

Comment: ,thanks for your response, even though your answer seems logical but why the same thing doesn't go with the Cr matrix, Cr(1,1) gives me 173 which is correct even though its a double times a unit8 and there's minuses allover.

Comment: @SALEMALA: the calculation of Cr has no negative constants. `a*R-b*V` is parsed as `(a*R)-(b*V)`. There are still rounding errors, but no values are saturated (clipped).

Comment: @SALEMALA: Actually, reordering the expression `Cb = -0.1687*R-0.3313*V+0.5*B+128` to `Cb = 0.5*B+128-0.1687*R-0.3313*V` should make it so you get the right answer.